# Set Leading space to UIView , Crashes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I need to **modify leading space of a View** . here is my code

```
    let advSearchViewAddLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:advancedSearchView,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem:self.view, 
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier:0,
        constant:200)
        self.view.addConstraint(advSearchViewAddLeadingConstraint)
```

By using this code i am getting crash as

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Unknown layout attribute'

Comment: why you are using `NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute` and a multiplier `0`, when you have to set a leading space constraint.

Comment: I have add view in storyboard i have added leading, trailing , top, bottom and height constraints . Now in View controller i need to change leading space dynamically based on data . at that time getting crash

Comment: have you added leading, trailing , top, bottom and height constraints with programatically  ??

Comment: No , i have added in storyboard . now i want to change leading space and height constraints , height constraints working fine and getting problem with leading space.

Comment: then add IBOutlet to your leading constaint in storyboard

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I would work at it the other way around. Create a containing view and drag an IBOutlet for leading space constraint. Then just change the constant, it should work better.

```
leadingConstraint.constant = 200
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `NSLayoutAttribute.Leading` instead of `NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute`. If you're providing two items, you need to specify the attribute of each item:

```
let advSearchViewAddLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint =
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:advancedSearchView,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem:self.view, 
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier:0,
        constant:200)
```

A couple of other notes:

- You can activate the constraint with: `advSearchViewAddLeadingConstraint.active = true`
- In Swift, type inference can help you out with enum types, so instead of typing `NSLayoutAttribute.Leading` you can just type `Leading`.